# Geometry Nodes - Wrapping instance on mesh - Scales (mermaid)

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

[image: wrap mesh node set up]

I am fallowing along with CG cookie trying to wrap some scales on a mesh to make a nice scaled fin
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmDv81dMQ6c (20m point)
however many of the nodes he's using are just...gone in 3.4 and 3.5 iv done the above to get it to work .... kidna and it does work for the most part but if I spin the model around...the scale is rotated 180 on its Z axis...and I cant seem to use any of the common tricks I'm finding to get it to track to another object of flip around or anything. Does any one have any suggestions on how to wrap to a mesh that gives an output like scales?

"correct scales"

[image]

Incorrect scale orientations

[image: incorrect scale orientation]

Comment: I think the problem you'fe facing likely has to do with the _Transfer Attribute_ node - you are correct, it has been removed for blender 3.4 and up, but this guy has a good workaround - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS7nsFNCRfY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender 3.0, your tutor could have used *Mesh to Points* on faces to simplify his tree. Nowadays, you can use *Dual Mesh* to create your offset grid. Both of those eliminate index-wrangling and transfer of normals in similar ways:

[image]

This version sets the size of scales relative to the underlying faces, and allows the user to set their tilt and swivel relative to surface normal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: trying now. looks much simpler and I like that output so far. What is the X,Y,1 node? I can see its a math node I think but not sure what one it would be. Arctan2? sorry I use blender as a blunt object I do not understand most of what I do.

Comment: @Wenth sorry, I just re-labelled a collapsed _Combine XYZ_ to make it unambiguous. To fit stuff in, I wind up H collapsing nodes quite a lot for illustration. If that conceals their meaning, I re-label.

Comment: Thanks Robin! was able to get everything working and it works much better then the older way! thank you.