# How to make scales

Tags: curve-modifier

I have a tail. There should be scales at the bottom of the tail (covering less than half of the tail)
I thought about using array+curve+ change size of scatters in curve mode, but it didn't work!!! I spend 3 hours and still doesn't figure out how it make work. I did it all following the tutorial. and I'm in deep despair now...

please help

[image]

Comment: here blender file https://blend-exchange.com/b/y7o7oxWk

Comment: can u pls add the link to the tutorial to your question? thx.

Comment: Since we don't know what tutorial you're following it's impossible to answer that question. Edit your question and include a link to the tutorial at the timestamp where the scales are added.

Comment: nevermind, I did it.
It was just tutorial from youtube where guy make a snake, I tried to repeated his steps with my idea

Comment: A search on 'Scales' on this site returns quite a few answers, including GN solutions, including https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/293085/35559 for example. I think, since you have a fix anyway, it's fair to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Based entirely on your picture, and without knowing exactly what effect you're trying to achieve, the following link may be of interest as an alternative tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkmCWCBI1CI

I'm not associated with the channel, but his content is excellent and very accessible, so I'd advocate checking out his other videos too.